# jQuery equivalant of mootools $$

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools, dollar-sign

I am migrating my code to jQuery from mootools. There is a line of code that uses mootools '$$' to get an array of elements with the given selectors

```
var myMenu =  $$('#outerDiv .menu');
```

I have tried `jQuery('#outerDiv .menu')` but it doesn't return an array.

Is there a way to use `'.find()'` from jQuery on the whole document ? (since I don't have a parent element to make it like parent.find().)

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly, and why do you need an array?

Comment: I needed the array, well , mostly to keep the functionality as such. ?Just that the mootools code needs to be changed to jQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest jQuery equivalent to [Mootools' `$$`](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Element/Element#Window%3adollars) would be calling `.get()` on a jQuery object:

```
var myMenu = jQuery('#outerDiv .menu').get();
```

From [`jQuery.fn.get` docs](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

> Without a parameter, `.get()` returns all of the elements [...]
>   All of matched DOM nodes are returned by this call, contained in a standard array.

When using jQuery though, you usually don't do this very often as the returned elements array won't support any jQuery method. Remember that jQuery handles iteration over DOM collections and methods chaining out of the box.